# How can I reduce the horizontal legend item/symbol width/padding/margin in Plotly?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly

I have a horizontal legend in a Plotly plot, however I'd like to reduce the amount of spacing between each symbol/label to preserve space. I've tried a number of options both in ggplot (including legend.spacing.x, and legend.key.width, but these aren't preserved when I convert the plot to a Plotly) and in Plotly (including the itemmargin, spacing, tracegroupgap layout settings - these only seem to work for vertical legends).

[image: Here's an image where I've tried to highlight the space I'm trying to remove]

And my code to reproduce that plot:

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = hp, color = as.factor(cyl))) +
  scale_color_discrete(name = '') +
  geom_point()

ggplotly(p) %>% 
  layout(legend = list(orientation = "h", y = 1.15, x = 0))
```

Any other ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### UPDATE: Based on Commented Use of Shiny

To add a dependency in Shiny, you need to both declare the dependency in the `ui` and modify the dependency in the plot.

> BTW: In this update, I combined methods 1 and 2 from the original answer. (All of the original content is still in this answer, just below the update.)

There is a call for `htmlDependency()`. That is added to the `ui`.
The function `fixDep` is unchanged from my original answer.

```
library(htmltools)  # only for htmlDependency()
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
library(shiny)

# update the Plotly dependency (UI and plot)

# this is for the UI
newDep <- htmlDependency(name = "plotly-latest",
                         version = "2.21.1", 
                         src = list(href = "https://cdn.plot.ly"),
                         script = "plotly-2.21.0.min.js")

# this is for the plot (same as in original answer)
fixDep <- function(plt) {
  # changes to dependency so that entrywidth/entrywidthmode work
  plt$dependencies[[5]]$src$file = NULL
  plt$dependencies[[5]]$src$href = "https://cdn.plot.ly"
  plt$dependencies[[5]]$script = "plotly-2.21.0.min.js"
  plt$dependencies[[5]]$local = FALSE
  plt$dependencies[[5]]$package = NULL
  plt
}
```

I added your plot two times here. That is to show you the differences whether you include the legend mods or not.

Please note that you have to change the dependency on *both* plots for this to work. (Even if you don't use the benefits of the updated dependency on both plots.)

I used `fluidPage`, but that's not required, you can probably use any `ui` formatter that works with `shiny`.

```
                         # your original plot (unchanged)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = hp, color = as.factor(cyl))) +
  scale_color_discrete(name = '') +
  geom_point()

ui <- fluidPage(
  createWebDependency(newDep),         # adding the dep to the UI
  ### the rest of your ui
  
  plotlyOutput("fixLegendSpacing"),    # added for reproducibility
  plotlyOutput("originalLegend")       # added for comparison
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$fixLegendSpacing <- renderPlotly({
    # your call for ggplotly, with JS for legend entry sizing
    ggplotly(p) %>% layout(legend = list(orientation = "h", y = 1.15, x = 0,
                                         entrywidth = 5)) %>%   # <<---- I added this!
      fixDep() %>% 
      htmlwidgets::onRender(
      "function(el, x) {
        what = el.querySelectorAll('text.legendtext');  /* Find all legend entries */
        gimme = what[1].x.baseVal[0].value;             /* Collect current px spacing */
        what.forEach(function(entry) {
          entry.setAttribute('x', gimme * .7)           /* Modify whitespace w/in entry */
        });
      }")
  })
  output$originalLegend <- renderPlotly({
    # your original call for ggplotly
    ggplotly(p) %>% layout(legend = list(orientation = "h", y = 1.15, x = 0)) %>% 
      fixDep()                     # <<------ you still have to change the dep here!
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Here are the plots as in this app.

[image]

---

---

#### Original Answer

The Plotly JS dependency that is used in the R Plotly package does not include the specific arguments designed for this type of modification, so it won't be an 'out-of-the-box' Plotly solution.

Here are two approaches you can use to control this spacing.

1. Use JS to modify the plot
2. Update the Plotly dependency

**NOTE** The Viewer pane will *not* reflect the change, you'll have to open it in your browser to see it.

To open a plot in your browser from RStudio's viewer pane, click on the rightmost icon in the menubar. (It's next to the broom.)

[image]

Here are the three legends aligned horizontally, original plot, method 1 (JS), and method 2 (updated dependency). You can see that the JS only changed within each entry, while the dependency update changed the overall size (without changing the font size).

[image]

##### Method 1: Use JS to modify the plot

This uses the package `htmlwidgets`, but as it's one call, I've just appended the library name to the function.

This modifies the SVG using Javascript. I've used .7 or 70%. Depending on what you're looking for this is the value that will increase or decrease the white space. I've added comments in the JS to explain a bit about what's happening.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

# your plot as you coded it
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = hp, color = as.factor(cyl))) +
  scale_color_discrete(name = '') +
  geom_point()

# your call for ggplotly, with JS for legend entry sizing
ggplotly(p) %>% layout(legend = list(orientation = "h", y = 1.15, x = 0)) %>% 
  htmlwidgets::onRender(
    "function(el, x) {
      what = el.querySelectorAll('text.legendtext');  /* Find all legend entries */
      gimme = what[1].x.baseVal[0].value;             /* Collect current px spacing */
      what.forEach(function(entry) {
        entry.setAttribute('x', gimme * .7)           /* Modify whitespace w/in entry */
      });
    }")
```

Using Method 1 (using JS):
[image]

##### Method 2: Update the Plotly dependency

This modifies the space for each entry, so the icon (dot, line, etc.) and the string that goes with it. This may not be particularly useful here.

The relative arguments are (along with Plotly's descriptions):

> **entrywidth**
> Code: fig.update_layout(legend_entrywidth=)
> Type: number greater than or equal to 0
> Sets the width (in px or fraction) of the legend. Use 0 to size the entry based on the text width, when `entrywidthmode` is set to "pixels".

> **entrywidthmode**
> Code: fig.update_layout(legend_entrywidthmode=)
> Type: enumerated , one of ( "fraction" | "pixels" )
> Default: "pixels"
> Determines what entrywidth means.

*****The coding I use here won't work if you're using Shiny.***** (If you are, let me know I can walk you through how to do this with Shiny, as well.)

Here is a function that will modify the Plotly dependency in your plot.

```
fixDep <- function(plt) {
  # changes to dependency so that entrywidth/entrywidthmode work
  plt$dependencies[[5]]$src$file = NULL
  plt$dependencies[[5]]$src$href = "https://cdn.plot.ly"
  plt$dependencies[[5]]$script = "plotly-2.21.0.min.js"
  plt$dependencies[[5]]$local = FALSE
  plt$dependencies[[5]]$package = NULL
  plt
}
```

###### All the code altogether

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)


fixDep <- function(plt) {
  # changes to dependency so that entrywidth/entrywidthmode work
  plt$dependencies[[5]]$src$file = NULL
  plt$dependencies[[5]]$src$href = "https://cdn.plot.ly"
  plt$dependencies[[5]]$script = "plotly-2.16.1.min.js"
  plt$dependencies[[5]]$local = FALSE
  plt$dependencies[[5]]$package = NULL
  plt
}


# your plot as you coded it
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = hp, color = as.factor(cyl))) +
  scale_color_discrete(name = '') +
  geom_point()

# your call for ggplotly, with additional calls for legend entry sizing
ggplotly(p) %>% 
  layout(legend = list(orientation = "h", y = 1.15, x = 0,
         entrywidth = 15)) %>% # <--- I added, using default entrywidthmode
  fixDep()
```

Using Method 2 (dependency):
[image]

---

---

If you have any questions, let me know.

Comment: Hi Kat, Thanks for such for this - very helpful! I probably should have been more specific. Is it possible to remove the space between each individual symbol rather than just the space between a symbol and its corresponding text? Ultimately, I want the entire legend to be shorter by reducing this space. So, for example, the space between 4 and the green symbol. Sorry if I didn't make that clear initially. Perhaps there's simply a different selector I can use and apply the same approach? (I would prefer to use the JS method as I am using Shiny). Thanks again!

Comment: If you look at the first method it changes the whitespace between the symbol and the text. However, the second method reduces the space between the entries (e.g., the space between the four and the green dot). You could use both methods at the same time, reducing space between and within each legend entry, as well.

Comment: Ah, I see, that makes sense. I that case, I have to be a pain and ask if you'd be able to show me what I need to do to use that method with Shiny. Thanks!

Comment: Not a pain! I've added the information and a reproducible app so you could see how it was incorporated. Let me know if you have any issues with it or have any other questions.